# Referencing keystore file for JSSE from Maven jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, resources, jsse

I am trying to write a simple client/server application using JSSE for SSL sockets. 
I have generated my own 'handmade' certificate with keytool for the server , and I have to set property 'keystore' as follow:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/keystore.ks");
```

The problem is the following:

As far as I understand, the setProperty wants just the name of the file , not the file itself.
From IDE it works just fine if I use the path to the file (i.e. src/main/resources/keystore.ks , using the standard maven directory structure )
The prpoblem come after I build the JAR with maven. The resource cannot be found.

I understand that resources files are copied in the root of JAR , but I didn't find any method to obtain the right filename to feed to setProperty.

I also tried

```
String pathKeystore=Server.class.getResource("/keystore.ks").getPath();
```

and also .toString() .toExternalForm() and so on. But none of it works if later I setProperty with this string.
Looking on other questions I see that the pathname is generally not used for resources, and instead you just read the file , but I need the String in my case.

I don't have a good understanding of what I am doing since I am new to Maven, but basically my question can be summed up as follow:

How to obtain the correct path name of a resource file to be used as a String for setProperty method in a maven-built JAR file?

Thanks in advance to everyone.

EDIT:
I considered also to set the property at runtime :
I launched my jar with

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.ks -jar my_jar.jar
```

I still set the password of this keystore in the code, since I don't have issue with the path with this.

I want to add that I had the same issue on my own client, I have to add the trustStore manually , and I launched it with

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts -jar my_client_jar.jar
```

This worked fine, and I guess this is the way that should be done, instead of using the filename.